# COBOL to Java converter in C#

Tags: java, c#, cobol

My company uses a lot of COBOL for our mainframe stuff, now we have a ton of off-shore and on-shore contractors that we work with that are Java developers but don't know any COBOL, it is the reverse for our Mainframe people which can cause communication errors.  Now I happen to know COBOL, Java, C# etc.  They want me to write a command line program to take in a textfile or cobol file and convert that input into Java so both sides can have a better understanding of what is going on.  Just look for some good references on how to get started, I would like to use C#.  I have some basic code to read in the file but really not sure what direction I should go.

I could separate the string using periods and then look for individual keywords and keep parsing from there but there has to be some sort of way to do it better.

Comment: Awww, good luck with that, you'll need it. More seriously: these two languages are *really really* different - I don't think a code translator could do a good job.

Comment: That is what worried me.

Comment: @zmbq's answer is the way I'd go.  However, if you insist on doing the conversion, I would suggest using a formal lexer/parser like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).  Hacking together a converter will quickly become a quagmire as you hit more complex syntax.  The time you take to learn to use a tool like ANTLR will pay off in the future.  There are ports of ANTLR available for many modern languages, including Java and C#.

Comment: I will talk to some people and hopefully they will see it as more trouble than it is worth but I will definitely checkout ANTLR in the meantime.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a lot harder than you think.   It helps to build such a tool using strong compiler technology as a foundation;  ANTLR is a place to start but only address the parsing part of the problem.   See http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html.  With sufficient effort, one can build such conversion tools; see http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Services/COBOLMigration.html.    I wouldn't try to use such a tool to help Java programmers understand COBOL though;  you're probably better off simply converting to Java and be done with legacy COBOL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid writing such a converter is not going to give anybody a better idea of anything (except for you, you'll be learning a great deal about parsing)

Machine translated code is very confusing and very hard to read. The Java people will be better off reading a COBOL book and then reading the legacy code.

Comment: I agree, using such a translator to help the Java coders doesn't seem like a particularly good idea.  It is true there a lot of bad translators in existence that produce ugly and confusing code.  But you don't have to use such (bad) tools.  Translated COBOL doesn't have to be confusing.